# Why is the past tense of "mind" not "mound?"

Tags: past-tense

I have never understood this.  It works this way for find/found, grind/ground, and others.  Why is it not mind/mound?

Comment: Because irregular verbs are not regular. _Mind_ is a regular verb, which means it takes _-ed_ for past tense. _Find_ and _grind_ are **irregular** verbs, which means their form changes in unpredictable ways. Most verbs are regular, but each irregular verb is irregular in its own ways. So don't look for patterns in irregularity; look for the regular patterns.

Answer (score 5):

*Find* and *grind* are [strong verbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germanic_strong_verb#Classes_1_to_6) that inherited Proto-Indo-European ablaut. They have been verbs for a very long time.

*Mind* is a weak verb. The Oxford English Dictionary describes its origin as "Formed within English, by conversion". In other words, the noun *mind* came first, and the verb *mind* was derived from the noun. Verbs that are derived from nouns cannot be strong verbs (unless they are altered by analogy). In fact, there is no productive way to derive new strong verbs. They're pretty much all inherited from at least Proto-Germanic verbs (I don't know, there might be a few that come from other sources).

This information is of limited usefulness for determining the conjugation of any particular verb, since often it's hard to tell if an English verb is derived from the corresponding noun, or vice versa (for example, *grind* and *find* also exist as nouns, via conversion/zero-derivation from the verbs).

Comment: I'll wait to accept to see if anything can top this, but that probably won't happen.  +1

Comment: _Strong verb_ is another term for _irregular verb_, and _weak_ is another term for _regular_, but referring to historical sources instead of present usage.

Comment: @JohnLawler That's not entirely accurate. A strong verb is a particular type of (synchronically) irregular verb. _Be_ and _have_ and the modals, for example, are irregular, but not strong. Regular verbs are always weak, but some irregular verbs can be weak, too (like _keep_ or _beat_).

Comment: Are you saying that English speakers have weak minds???

Comment: @Hellion But strong mounds!